# How do I use "custom filter" prop in data tables in vuetify? or How do I create a custom filter to filter by headers?

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js

As of date of posting, I cannot find any documentation to use the "custom filter" prop in data tables.

I just want to create a custom filter to filter my data table by headers.
I have a dropdown, and when user click on one of the options for the dropdown, it will filter the list for one specific header.

Example:
Dropdown options: 
Food type: fruit, meat, vegetable

1. Bakchoi       (vegetable)
2. Pork          (meat)
3. Chicken Thigh (meat)
4. watermelon    (fruit)

If I select dropdown as meat, it should only show me pork and chicken thigh.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am searching for the same info.

Comment: Hey Sterling, sorry for the late reply. I was removed from the position before I had the chance to solve it. So I can't say I found the solution, but I believe one of the answers below should be able to help you. :)

Answer (score 46):

Looking at the code on Github<sup>1</sup>, it looks like the `customFilter` prop is used to overwrite the default method used to determine how the `filter` prop is applied to the items in the table.

The default `customFilter` method applies the `filter` function to each property name of each item object and filters out any items that don't include one property name that passes the filter:

> ```
> customFilter: {
>   type: Function,
>   default: (items, search, filter) => {
>     search = search.toString().toLowerCase()
>     return items.filter(i => (
>       Object.keys(i).some(j => filter(i[j], search))
>     ))
>   }
> },
> ```

You might want to overwrite this function if you wanted to prevent any columns from being included in the filter or if there were specific rows that you always wanted to prevent from being filtered out.

You'll notice that the method also depends on the `search` prop, which must be a string.

---

All that said, you really don't need to use that prop for what you want to do. You should just make a computed property to filter the items based on your dropdown value and pass that computed property as the `items` prop.

Here's an example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      food: [
        { name: 'Bakchoi', type: 'vegetable', calories: 100 },
        { name: 'Pork', type: 'meat', calories: 200 },
        { name: 'Chicken Thigh', type: 'meat', calories: 300 },
        { name: 'Watermelon', type: 'fruit', calories: 10 },
      ],
      headers: [
        { text: 'Name', align: 'left', value: 'name' },
        { text: 'Food Type', align: 'left', value: 'type' }, 
        { text: 'Calories', align: 'left', value: 'calories' },
      ],
      foodType: null,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredItems() {
      return this.food.filter((i) => {
        return !this.foodType || (i.type === this.foodType);
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.15.2/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.15.2/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>  
    <v-select 
      label="Food Type" 
      :items="['vegetable', 'meat', 'fruit']"
      v-model="foodType"
    ></v-select>
    
    <v-data-table 
      :headers="headers"
      :items="filteredItems"
      hide-actions
    >
      <template slot="items" scope="{ item }">
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.type }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.calories }}</td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

---

1. This answer was written when Vuetify was at v0.15.2. [The source code for the `VDataTable` component at that version can be found here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/8e3eec8ae0ed4f078693109bd7659d359e69979b/src/components/VDataTable/VDataTable.vue).

Comment: Using a custom computed property versus a custom filter has slightly different behaviour.  If you use a custom computed property and there are no results, the data table will show the no-data slot.  If you use a custom filter and there are no results, the data table will show the no-results slot.  The difference is often important.

Comment: @KJohnson You could get around the differences by using the `no-data` slot and customizing the message based on if the lack of data is coming from the source or the computed property's filter.

Comment: Link to source is broken

Answer (score 13):

You can also go the customFilter approach like this, I've restricted the search to the type field.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            food: [
                { name: 'Bakchoi', type: 'vegetable', calories: 100 },
                { name: 'Pork', type: 'meat', calories: 200 },
                { name: 'Chicken Thigh', type: 'meat', calories: 300 },
                { name: 'Watermelon', type: 'fruit', calories: 10 },
            ],
            headers: [
                { text: 'Name', align: 'left', value: 'name' },
                { text: 'Food Type', align: 'left', value: 'type' },
                { text: 'Calories', align: 'left', value: 'calories' },
            ],
            search: '',

        };
    },
    methods: {
        customFilter(items, search, filter) {

            search = search.toString().toLowerCase()
            return items.filter(row => filter(row["type"], search));

        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.15.2/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.15.2/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons">

<div id="app">
    <v-app>
        <v-select
                label="Food Type"
                :items="['vegetable', 'meat', 'fruit']"
                v-model="search"
        ></v-select>

        <v-data-table
                :headers="headers"
                :items="food"
                :search="search"
                :custom-filter="customFilter"
                hide-actions
        >
            <template slot="items" scope="{ item }">
                <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.type }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.calories }}</td>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
    </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Using this approach will call the `customFilter` method twice (See: https://codepen.io/yosafatade/pen/axMooM and open the console window). This would be a performance problem if you have large data.

Comment: I created an issue about the problem I mentioned above in Github: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/7090

and you can see the work around for vuetify v-1 : https://codepen.io/yosafatade/pen/gyEKeW

Answer (score 2):

In my case I have 2 different way of filtering which are search bar and drop down. I tried to use `custom-filter` for both of them, but it doesn't work, so I came up with another approach

```
<v-text-field v-model="search" label="Label"></v-text-field>
<v-select
    v-model="select"
    :items="food"
    item-text="type"
    item-value="type"
    :label="Types"
    @change="filterFoodUsingDropDown"
>
</v-select>
<v-data-table
    :search="search"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="food"
    :custom-filter="filterFoodUsingSearchbar"
>
```

```
data() {
    return {
        food: [
            { name: 'Bakchoi', type: 'vegetable', calories: 100 },
            { name: 'Pork', type: 'meat', calories: 200 },
            { name: 'Chicken Thigh', type: 'meat', calories: 300 },
            { name: 'Watermelon', type: 'fruit', calories: 10 },
        ],
        headers: [
            { text: 'Name', align: 'left', value: 'name' },
            { text: 'Food Type', align: 'left', value: 'type' },
            { text: 'Calories', align: 'left', value: 'calories' },
        ],
        search: '',
        select: '',
    };
},
methods: {
    filterFoodUsingSearchbar(items, search, filter) {
            // Condition
    }
        
    filterFoodUsingDropDown() {
        if (this.select !== '') {
            // In this case I use vuex to store the original data of the 
               food so that all the data is still exist even we filtered it out
            this.food = this.$store.state.food.filter((item) => item.type === this.select)
        }
    }
```

Comment: The proper way would be to use the `:custom-key-filter` option... i.e. `:custom-key-filter="{'myHeaderKey': myHeaderKeyFilter}"`
 However, until the Vuetify bug ([10815](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/10815)) is fixed, this answer seems to be the best option.